# how to center the first item in a flexbox slider/carousel

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to build a simple scroll slider with flexbox with three items. I want the first item to be centered in the page (under the headline) but the following items only should have a less margin.

HTML:

```
<div class="page-width">
  <h1>Headline</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-wrapper">
      Center me
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-wrapper">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-wrapper">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page-width {
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.flex-item {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.flex-wrapper {
  background: blue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

How can I achieve to center the first item, while the second and third only remain with a margin of 20px? Also, it should be responsive, for example when the page width is smaller, the first item should still be centered.

I tried to use

```
.flex-item {
  flex: 0 0 100%
}
```

and center the wrapper inside, so the box would be in the center, but then the second and third item are outside of the screen.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ascena/pen/wvqZgzg

Comment: I didn't understand, Do you want your first item to have the full width of the carousel?

Comment: @Mohsen007 I want it as Arezou Saremian made it, but the first box should be centered, on every viewport (e.g. .page-width gets smaller)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.page-width {
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 5px solid green;

}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: scroll;  
  padding-left:20%;
}

.flex-item {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.flex-wrapper {
  background: blue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-width">
  <h1>Headline</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-wrapper">
      Center me
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-wrapper">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-wrapper">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how does 20% works? will the first box be centered in every viewport by this? Edit: If the .page-width container gets smaller, the padding: 20%; does not work anymore.

Comment: is 20% just a Magic Number? margin-left: 20px?

Answer (score 0):

In case you never got an answer or for anyone else wanting the same thing. You need to add margin left to the first item

```
.flex-item:first-child {
  margin-left: calc( 50% - 125px );
}
```

50% pushes it to half, then minus 125px which is the width of the box divided by 2.

```css
.page-width {
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.flex-item {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.flex-item:first-child {
  margin-left: calc(50% - 125px);
}
.flex-wrapper {
  background: blue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-width">
  <h1>Headline</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-wrapper">
      Please center me
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-wrapper">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="flex-wrapper">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```